# What's up with the new colors

Tags: bug, status-norepro, design

Um, the title headings of questions, tags, ect. are pale to the point of unreadablity.  Veiwing in internet explorer 8.

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce this -- the site looks fine to me in both IE8 and IE7 (IE8 in compatibility mode). Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: For most of yesterday http://sstatic.net/cooking/img/bg-header.png was 404'ing. It appears to be fixed now.

Comment: It looked like this: http://i.imgur.com/IYCZ4.png

Comment: yeah, seems fixed now.